# JUnit Test cases not executing after adding testng dependency in Maven project

Tags: junit, testng

We have a maven project which runs fine and execute JUnit test cases. We wanted to generate html reports so we added dependencies for testng, now no test cases are executed, if we remove dependency of testng test cases runs again.

Here are all the dependencies.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.50.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG is not library for generating test reports. It is an alternative test framework that you can use instead of JUnit. For generating reports please have a look at [Maven's Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).